# Keep working while Message Box is displayed

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a code on vba and I display the results using the MsgBox. I want to keep these results displayed as I enter the result values in a separate excel file but Excel doesn't allow me to work on another excel file until I press OK or Cancel button on MsgBox. How do keep msgbox on and still work on the separate excel file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `MsgBox`. Use a customized `Userform` instead and then call it showing it as modeless

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
    MsgBox "Hello World"
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub
```

can be also written as

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Hello World"
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub
```